# asp.net event is not firing up need assistance

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sql-server, bootstrap-4

I am trying to run an event behind my `asp:Button`.

What I am trying to do is loading some `usercontrolforms` in a scrollable div

The code of that is this:

```
    <div ruant="server" class="Lead1">
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="Lead1">

            </asp:PlaceHolder>
            </div>
```

and the code of my `usercontrolform` is

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UCLeadTemplate.ascx.cs" Inherits="CRM_MGC_FINAL.UCLeadTemplate" %>
~~~
<asp:Panel id="div" CssClass="v" runat="server" BorderStyle="Groove">
    <div runat="server" class="tdiv">
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Lid" CssClass="v1" Text="#id"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="h3" CssClass="v2" Text=" Admin Name"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="h6" CssClass="v3" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </div>
    <div runat="server" class="adiv">
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAction"  CssClass="v4" Text=">"  OnClick="btnAction_Click" OnClientClick="myfunction();" CausesValidation="True" /> 
        <script>
            function myfunction() {
                btnAction.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnAction_Click);
                __doPostBack('<%= btnAction.ClientID%>', '');
            }
</script>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

As you can see, I have done some research and found some javascript code to register my `onclick` event but it is still not working and my asp.net page got reloaded with any functionality. I also set a debugger on it, but it is not triggering.

I want to know how I can trigger my event against my `btnAction` button to run some code for me.

Thanks

Comment: Your script is running on the client. Wire up the event handler in your `UCLeadTemplate.ascx.cs` file.

Comment: yes but i have another division that i wanna pop up some result according to the button clicked

Comment: what i am doing is loading a bunch of these usercontrolform and having different type of information in it about some clients.then after the btnAction of those usercontrolform is click i am trying to retrieve the id of that info to generate some results on the other divisions but my event is not firing up

Comment: You can't wire up server side click handlers on the client side. If you want to wire up a button's server side click handler, it must be done from the server side.

Comment: i have done that in the OnClick attribute but it is not firing up instead it refresh the whole page and i lost everything. so can you guide me how can i hook a server side click handler beside click as it is not working or can you tell what i am doing wrong in this

Comment: and sorry for late reply as i am also testing some codes to make it working

Comment: If you do click on a button and it is posting back to the server, then this of course causes a round trip. That's what `Page.IsPostback` is for.

Comment: can you show me some examples i didnt quite get that, right now i am assuming that you are talking about Page_Load method where we check `if(isPostBack){//code}` if not then show me some examples